# How to get cell value from LibreOfficeCalc document using COM object?

Tags: lua, com, libreoffice-calc

I'm writing a script in Lua and using the luacom library. I need to get the value of a specific cell. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
self._myLOCdoc = luacom.CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
self._desktop = self._myLOCdoc:createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
self._workbook = self._desktop:loadComponentFromURL("file:///" .. file_path, "_blank", 0, {ReadOnly = false})
self._worksheet = _workbook:getSheets():getByIndex(0)
local cell = self._worksheet:getCellByPosition(0, 0)
local cellValue = cell:getValue()
```

I'm trying to get the value of cell A1. But getValue() can only return a numeric value; if there is a string in the cell, then nothing will work. How can I get the value of a cell regardless of the data type in it?

Comment: You can first get [getType()](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/table/XCell.html#getType) for this cell and depending on the value received, use `getValue()` or `getString()`. Or just use [**getDataArray()**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XCellRangeData.html#getDataArray)